# Don't execute SVN "post commit hook" when a specific file is committed

Tags: windows, svn, visualsvn-server, post-commit-hook

Is there any way to not to run "post commit hook" or skip "post commit hook statement" when a specific file is committed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a test in your `post-commit` script. The `svnlook changed repository_directory` will show which files changed - can use `grep` or similar.

For example:

```
#!/bin/sh

/usr/bin/svnlook changed /svn/repo | grep -w ' yourfile$' && exit 0

# here begin the main part of your (original) hook
```

Comment: "C:\Program Files\VisualSVN Server\bin\svnlook" changed C:\Repositories\sbm2 | findstr version.json                                                          ----------------------How to stop execution, it is still executing

Comment: Ah, Windows. Did you try add `&& exit 0` as I describe in example? https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html

Comment: This could fail if there are files whose name is a superstring of *yourfile.* Perhaps better use `grep -Fx` with the full path to the file.

Comment: @tripleee please check `-w` in `grep` options.
But in this case it's irrelevant because the OP uses Windows.

Comment: No, it's not. `grep -w yourfile` matches `not-yourfile.too`, on Windows just as on every other platform.

Comment: On FreeBSD doesn't: `echo 'not_yourfile.too' | grep -w yourfile` prints nothing (and returns error code 1).
The OP uses Windows without Cygwin, and replaces `grep` to `findstr` (see his first comment).

Comment: Sorry, switched the underscore to a minus before I saw your reply. The point remains; `-w` reduces the chance of false positives, but by no means eliminates it. Projects with files with similar names are more common than you seem to think.

Comment: You've right. But the `-x` doesn't work because `svnlook changed` has a plus letter (see http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svnlook.c.changed.html). Would better `grep " yourfile$"`.

Comment: @RajSharma check the documentation: https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html - I think you should use `||` instead of `&&` because `findstr` returns `false` if found the pattern and returns `true` if not found.

Comment: "C:\Program Files\VisualSVN Server\bin\svnlook" changed C:\Repositories\sbm2| findstr version.json && EXIT /B     #thanks @uzsolt

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
"C:\Program Files\VisualSVN Server\bin\svnlook" changed C:\Repositories\sbm2| findstr version.json && EXIT /B
#here my main part of post-commit-hook will begin
```

Thanks @uzsolt